# Programmatically add comments and linebreaks to XmlSchema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm using the [`System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschema) class to create an xml schema programmatically, but it becomes unreadable by its size. Is there a way to output comments and linebreaks?

This is a part of my code:

```
XmlSchema schema = new XmlSchema();
schema.TargetNamespace = "my-ns";
schema.Namespaces.Add("","my-ns");

// do stuff here
...

// and then add some comments like <!-- here comes the second part -->
schema.Items.Add(COMMENTLINE); // How does this work? A line break will be fine too.

// and do more stuff
...

// then write it to a file
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;

using(XmlWriter tw = XmlTextWriter.Create(filename, settings)
{
    schema.Write(tw);
}
```

Desired output:

```
<xs:element>
  <!-- comment my stuff -->
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an XML document.  Just use a pretty-printer.

Comment: `XmlSchema` is not an `XmlDocument` as far as I know. How can I add comments to the XmlSchema?